# How virtual address is translated in physical on x86-64?

Tags: memory

I have some problems with understanding, how virtual adress is translated in physical adress on x86-64. Especially, 39-12 bits of PTE describe PFN of physical page. The number of these bits is 28. 12 bits (from 0 to 11) of virtual adress describe the offset in this physical page. To sum up, we have 28 bits (PFN) and 12 bits(offset). Summing we have 40 bits, but physical adress should contain 64 bits, is it so??? Where is error in my reasoning????

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow.com :). I think, russinovich windows internals book helps you. Take a look at chapter about memory - http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/20285651/

Comment: @KostiaShiian there is example of x86-32, and it's ok, summing 20 bits of PFN and 12 bits of offset, we get 32 bits and it is physical adress. but i have problems only with x86-64

Comment: Current x64 processors have 40 address pins.  A terabyte of RAM is enough for everybody.  At least until the pesky disk speed problems will be solved.

Answer (score 1):

64-bit CPUs do *not* necessarily have a 64-bit address bus.  The virtual address space is 64 bits, but the physical address space only has to be large enough to support the largest reasonable amount of RAM.

I can't find a reference at the moment, but 40 bits (one terabyte) sounds about right.